# Can`t insert DATE to mssql via FreeTDS bcp API on linux

Tags: c++, sql-server, bcp, freetds

When i try to insert DATE via FreeTDS bcp on linux i`m facing with that error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

```
create table test (c_date date);
```

Bind type of this column is SYBCHAR, on windows i haven`t problems but i use WinApi

```
...
char buff[10];
time_t time = ACE_OS::time(nullptr);
struct tm *tmp = localtime(&time);
strftime(buff, 10, "%Y-%m-%d", tmp); /// example: 2008-10-22
bcp_collen(db, 10, 1);
bcp_colptr(db, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(buff), 1);
bcp_sendrow(db);
bcp_batch(db); /// here the exception is thrown
```

I have tried to use another patterns for dateformat such as `%Y%m%d`,`%Y/%m/%d` etc., another binding types, creating locales.conf near freetds.conf, but nothing...

Comment: The unambiguous date format is `YYYYMMDD`, not `YYYY-MM-DD`. For the date+time types, the unambiguous format is ISO8601 (ie `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm......`). Removing the date separators in ISO8601 works too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried that format too, but unfortunately i got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to insert Date, if you are facing with the same problem you should to convert to UCS2.

[Before data status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5wW.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouV0y.png)

Answer (score 0):

To use a SQL Server `date` field, you have to be using at least FreeTDS version `0.95` and specify `TDS_Version` of at least `7.3` in your connection.

The types `time`, `date`, `datetime2`, and `datetimeoffset` were introduced in SQL Server 2008, which was the first version support TDS Version 7.3:

https://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

It is likely you are connecting with TDS Version < 7.3, or if you specified TDS Version 8.0, it actually maps to 7.1. Try explicitly setting to version 7.3, and make sure your FreeTDS version is 0.95 or above.